# Convert a string of characters to ascii values

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, ascii

I have been searching through the internet on how to do this but have failed to find a way to actually do it..

Basically, I have a series of large dataframes, and I wish to convert one of the column vectors in all of these datasets from a string of characters, say for example: ASDFSDFSAFDSA, to its equivalent in ASCII format. I want to do this in bash because they are too large to process in R.

I know in java and R there are functions that do this, but have failed to find its equivalent in bash. I have looked at the `xxd` function as well as some posts on the forum but they end up giving me just a couple of integers rather than the proper ASCII format.

Here is the `dput` output of a small snippet of the data:

```
structure(list(Clone.ID = 0:5, Clone.count = c(2454L, 1915L, 
1369L, 1255L, 1152L, 1099L), AA..Seq..CDR3 = c("CASSNSDRTYGDNEQFF", 
"CATSSVLTQQETQYF", "CASSSRGLANTQYF", "CASSLGTALNTEAFF", "CASSRRHLGNTGELFF", 
"CASSEGRSNQPQHF")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data uploaded looks like this:

```
    Clone.ID Clone.count   AA..Seq..CDR3
1        0        2454 CASSNSDRTYGDNEQFF
2        1        1915   CATSSVLTQQETQYF
3        2        1369    CASSSRGLANTQYF
4        3        1255   CASSLGTALNTEAFF
5        4        1152  CASSRRHLGNTGELFF
6        5        1099    CASSEGRSNQPQHF
```

The desired output would be for the `col` AA..Seq.CDR3 to have the following entries instead:

```
067 065 083 083 078 083 068 082 084 089 071 068 078 069 081 070 070
067 065 084 083 083 086 076 084 081 081 069 084 081 089 070
067 065 083 083 083 082 071 076 065 078 084 081 089 070 #and so on...
```

Also, it would be ideal if the ascii representation was as an integer rather than an array of ints as is the output for R's conversion - and pythons too I believe.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you all for your time,

Comment: Do you really want to do it "in bash"? or are you asking about suitable command line utilities such as Awk, Perl, Python etc.?

Comment: Good point. Any command line utility really would work. Are you recommending I use the python interface in bash for this command? I know a similar function exists there too

Comment: It's hard to know what to recommend without knowing the structure + format of your data

Comment: The string of characters have no whitespaces and are just a sequence of letters for all entries in the dataframe. Wrt the dataframes, they are 3 cols x many many thousands of rows, all integers. I wanna convert the sequences to ascii characters in order to upload it in R as a `bigmemory` object

Comment: Please post a minimal example (say, 3 cols x 5 rows) along with the expected output

Comment: Just uploaded, basically, I just want to convert the sequences in the 3rd column to their equivalent ascii values

Comment: If awk can filter the file line by line and pick out the column you need... What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... may I ask **why** you want to do this? I would personally probably do the reverse, 'causr I'm more fluent in letters than in decimal codes..

However, let's rephrase your problem cl to more precisely define the goal:
- you have in a table a **column of ASCII chars** in the range A-Z (or is it also lower case?)
- you want each character to be translated with its **decimal cvalue over one space and 3 digits**

Bash has a powerful string / char replacement, eg

zz=CABXAB;echo ${zz//A/' 065'}

Comment: The case of the letters is of no importance really. The aim of this is to be able to import the dataframe into R, as the files are too large to be uploaded as is. Should it be converted to ints, I would be able to upload it as a `bigmemory` object and then do all the analysis as such..

Comment: Also, I have tried running your code but got a weird output: C 065BX 065B... Is this normal ?

Comment: 1 - the weird output is normal in that case since I'm translating only the letter A.

Comment: Okaay... now I understand. How would you do it for the whole string though? I mean, without having to manually encode for all letters in the alphabet. Thanks btw for your response!

Comment: 2 - However this solution seems rather painful in your case where you have to translate lots of text.
I would probably use some higher-level language to build and run the conversion, ie wit a function such as php str_replace http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php or its equivalent in perl (which I don't know)

Comment: But this seems really a dead direction, since we know more on the structure of data..

Comment: So in fact we replace each char with its ascii code in format ' 000'

Answer (score 1):

You could do something quick'n'dirty in Perl:

```
$ perl -alne 'print join " ", map { ord $_ } split //, $F[3] if $. > 1' datafile
67 65 83 83 78 83 68 82 84 89 71 68 78 69 81 70 70
67 65 84 83 83 86 76 84 81 81 69 84 81 89 70
67 65 83 83 83 82 71 76 65 78 84 81 89 70
67 65 83 83 76 71 84 65 76 78 84 69 65 70 70
67 65 83 83 82 82 72 76 71 78 84 71 69 76 70 70
67 65 83 83 69 71 82 83 78 81 80 81 72 70
```

However if you are already processing the data in `R`, then you should consider using its native `utf8ToInt` as described here [R: How to convert characters into ASCII code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32161001/4440445)